# How to use a .txt file instead of .dat file in AS3 to test air for android app in flash pro cs6

Tags: android, actionscript-3, adobe, flash-cs6

Hi i want my app which im making in flash pro cs6 using air for android to read the speed from .txt file instead of a .dat file.

How do i go about changing this code below done in Actionscript 3 to do this as i want it to be easier to change the numbers and test the speedometer App works again with different speed info.

Also could you let me know how would i put the numbers in the .txt file to be read.

At the moment i am  just using gps binary logged speed file from my phone to test this but i cannot change the values of this .dat file so i can't test some top speeds.

Here is the code i have how would i rectify to use a txt file:

```
package
{
import flash.events.EventDispatcher;
import flash.events.GeolocationEvent;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;
import flash.filesystem.File;
import flash.filesystem.FileMode;
import flash.filesystem.FileStream;
import flash.utils.Timer;

public class GeolocationSimulate
    extends EventDispatcher
    implements IGeolocation
{   
    static private const DEFAULT_DELAY :Number = 1000;
    static private const FILE          :String = "gps.dat";

    private var filestream :FileStream;
    private var timer      :Timer;

    public function GeolocationSimulate()
    {
        timer = new Timer( DEFAULT_DELAY );
        timer.addEventListener( TimerEvent.TIMER, handleTimer );
        timer.start();

        var file :File = File.userDirectory;
        file = file.resolvePath( FILE );            
        filestream = new FileStream();
        filestream.open( file, FileMode.READ );
    }

    public function setRequestedUpdateInterval( interval :Number ) :void
    {
        timer.delay = interval;
    }

    private function handleTimer( e :TimerEvent ) :void
    {
        if( filestream != null )
        {
            var speed :Number;

            if( filestream.bytesAvailable )
            {
                speed = filestream.readFloat();
            }
            else
            {
                filestream.position = 0;
                speed = filestream.readFloat();
            }

            dispatchEvent(
                new GeolocationEvent(
                    GeolocationEvent.UPDATE,
                    false,
                    false,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    speed,
                    0,
                    0
                )
            );
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: anyone please help im really stuck on this

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that's what you want but you can write text to a file this way :

```
    var file :File = File.userDirectory;
    file = file.resolvePath( FILE );            
    filestream = new FileStream();
    filestream.open( file, FileMode.WRITE); (or FileMode.APPEND if you want to add text to end of existing file)
    filestream.writeUTFBytes(yourTextHere);
    filestream.close();
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but i may have made you misunderstand the question what i want is my above code to read a .txt file instead of a binary .dat file which i cant edit as it's just gps number that were stored on my phone whilst i was driving,  which i have copied and have been using to simulate my speedometer app whilst testing on my computer is it possible to modify my code to use a .txt instead of there other .dat file i been using do this at all.